# On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, which CUDA is required by the Cycles - CUDA XX.xx from nvidia's website or the cuda-toolkit available in official repo

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.03 LTS on my desktop as well as my laptop and I wish to use Cycles rendering engine in Blender.

**For desktop:**

I installed the nvidia drivers with the usual command -

`ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Then I downloaded the CUDA 11.6 local package from [Nvidia's official website](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11-4-3-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=20.04&target_type=deb_local)

Then I followed the instructions given on the page and installed CUDA on my desktop.

Result: Cycles renders fantastic!

**For laptop:**

I installed Nvidia drivers in the same way as I had with the desktop.

But when I tried installing CUDA in the same way, I am faced with a problem.

Ubuntu has an official package cuda-toolkit and I have a .deb package downloaded from Nvidia's official site.

> **The question now is: WHICH ONE DO I INSTALL FOR CYCLES RENDERING?**

**Is the official cuda-toolkit package sufficient or is the CUDA 11.6 .deb file downloaded from Nvidia's website needs to be installed.**

NOTE: The .deb file downloaded from Nvidia's website seems to cause dependency problems on laptop. So I'm wary of installing it.

My Nvidia graphic card's info is as shown in the image below -

[image]

Comment: I just installed the nvidia drivers and not a separate Cuda install. It seems to be Cuda 11.4, but it works fine with Cycles.

Comment: @Dale Cieslak Good to know. Yes, Cycles does work with just drivers. But I've noticed that Cycles renders very fast with CUDA 11.4 on my desktop. Without it, Cycle wasn't this fast. I suspect there might be some connection between Cycles and CUDA software after all.