Nvidia Cuda Optix under Ubuntu
After a very long battle against the Ubuntu nvidia driver 560, 550, 545, now I get my Nvidia RTX 2060 to work, but in Blender I can’t enable CUDA rendering nor can I use Optix.
The error it shows is, i have the install a driver more than 470, but I got the 545.
What do I have to enable or to configure auto to install in oben to 2204 to use the optics or Kuda, system?

I'm not so sure but i think this is more suitable for Ubuntu stackexchange, but i'm not very sure about it

Have you installed the cuda-toolkit? It's mentioned in these related questions: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/111150/107598, https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/253048/107598, https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/82528/107598. Also, make sure your user is in the video group as mentioned in one of the answers.

Thanks for your help. I tried, but I thing I have a deeper problem in Ubuntu. I can't use the driver 560, 550, 545, 535, 515, and 470. Only the xServer org driver works. As soon as I install one of the Priority driver or one of the Nvidia driver, the screen stops working and I can't see only a black screen. :(
